# JVM exits without any error messages when loading compiled DLL

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a c function from Java.
When loading the library (in Test.java) 2 things happen randomly:

- "Load Lib" gets printed, and the jvm just exits without any errors
- "Load Lib" gets printed, and the jvm gets stuck in a loop

The weird thing is that 'sometimes' "Lib loaded" gets printed too. Which means the library got loaded...

My question is that how can I fix this? The real problem is that I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Dll compilation steps:

- gcc -fpic -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\include" -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\include\win32" -c BindLib.c BindLib.h
- gcc -fpic -s -shared -o BindLib.dll BindLib.o

System info:

- Windows 10 64 bit, version 1909
- Java 15

Main file:

```java
package degubi;

public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.enable();
    }
}
```

Library file:

```java
package degubi;

public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Load lib");
        System.loadLibrary("BindLib");
        System.out.println("Lib loaded");
    }

    public static native void enable();
}
```

Source file:

```c
#include "windows.h"
#include "BindLib.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_degubi_Test_enable(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz) {

}
```

Header file:

```c
#define __int64 long long
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class degubi_Test */

#ifndef _Included_degubi_Test
#define _Included_degubi_Test
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     degubi_Test
 * Method:    enable
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_degubi_Test_enable(JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a project in Visual Studio and building it from there... worked perfectly. Still don't know what caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which shell and C compiler were you using?
The problem might come from the incompatible between C compiler & the shell environment.

For example, if you use Cygwin compiler to compile the DLL, then execute the binary on Windows CMD, the program might not work (dependencies on cygwin.dll).

Comment: I used Cygwin for compilation.
I tried it running inside the IDE and in CMD (jar created with 'mvn clean install', ran with java -jar 'jarName')
Same thing happened every time

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.
If you compile the native library on Cygwin, then it's better to run it on Cygwin shell.